# Bash, convert a path contains * to string without expansion

Tags: command-line, bash

Here is my code

```
dataPath="/path/to/**/*.json"
python main.py --data-path $dataPath
```

But the bash considers the `dataPath` is path and unroll the `dataPath` to command line arguments, finally returns command line arguments error. Instead, the following is OK

```
python main.py --data-path "/path/to/**/*.json"
```

I cannot understand why.

Comment: Does `dataPath` contain whitespaces? What if you enclose `$dataPath` with `"`?

Comment: ** double star needs globstar enabled. `shopt -s globstar`

Comment: @Kulfy No, there are many folder in `dataPath`.

Comment: @bac0n Can you answer it more? Or just answer this question below?

Comment: In the terms used in the bash manual pages, `*` is a "special pattern character" that must be quoted in order to prevent the shell from subjecting it to *pathname expansion*

Comment: @bac0n Enabling `globstar` would not help here, because the goal is to pass the glob pattern unexpanded to a Python program that then expands it (which is what the command reported to produce the desired result is doing). To achieve that, the shell needs to be *prevented* from expanding it at all (as steeldriver commented). I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$dataPath`, on which [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) is performed, is not [quoted](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting). Enclose it in [double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes) as `"$dataPath"`:

```bsh
python main.py --data-path "$dataPath"
```

When parameter expansion and other expansions triggered by `$` (or `` ` ``) occur unquoted, [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) and [globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) are performed on the result. [Only rarely would you actually want those things to happen.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Word splitting, also called field splitting, splits up the results of an expansion to be passed as multiple arguments. By default it splits on whitespace. (This is controlled by the special `IFS` shell variable.)

Globbing, which is also called filename expansion or pathname expansion, treats the character `*`, `?`, and `[` specially. If any such character appears, the text is treated as a pattern representing any number of filenames, and the shell attempts to expand it to a list of such filenames. This also can--and often does--generate multiple arguments, one per filename.

You intend the `*` characters to be treated specially, but by your Python program, *not the shell*. Since `$dataPath` expands to them, you must quote it with double quotes to protect the `*` characters from triggering an expansion by the shell, so that they are passed literally to your Python program.

When you run `python main.py --data-path "/path/to/**/*.json"`, that's what you're doing, which is why that works. You could also use [single quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes) in place of double quotes there. In `python main.py --data-path "$dataPath"`, you *must* use double quotes, since single quotes are too strong: they would prevent parameter expansion too, and the literal text `$dataPath` would be passed to your Python program.

Finally, note that you do *not* need to enable the `globstar` shell option for this to work. Although your pattern is a recursive glob (it uses `**` to match arbitrarily many path components), the goal here is for your Python program, *not* the shell, to expand that pattern. The way your Python program will treat the pattern is unaffected by what shell options are enabled in the shell you use to execute the Python interpreter.